# One hot encoding vs. label encoder in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have a data frame in which all columns are categorical. In some of these categorical columns, there are some columns which the data inside each category has an order.

For example in column A: Doctorate degree, MSC degree, Bachelor Degree (Doctorate is higher than MSC and MSC is higher than Bachelor)

But there are other columns which they don't have order.

For example in column B: Male, Female, Other

If we do one hot encoding for all columns it means that it will not matter there is an order between data in columns.
What if we encode the columns with an order with label encoder and columns without order with one hot encoding?
Is it ok to implement 2 methods of encoding in one data frame?

for column A with label encoder, we will have: 2, 1,0

for column B with one hot encoding, we will have: 3 columns between 0 and 1

Comment: re: "Is it ok to implement 2 methods of encoding in one data frame?" It is generally _"OK"_ to do whatever you need to do to _accurately represent_ the data

Comment: It will increase the accuracy of regression methods. but It has a negative effect on the feature selection method. because columns without order are between 0 and 1 but columns with order have a higher label and it will make them more important than the other columns no matter if they are important on the target value or not. @G.Anderson

Comment: If that is negatively impacting model performance, then you can normalize all the categorical columns between 0 and 1. This may be a better question on https://datascience.stackexchange.com since it relates to theory and not to coding directly